# Integrating sequence diagram into markdown file

Tags: markdown, sequence-diagram

I want to find the right tool to integrate Diagram into Markdown files. 
I found [js-sequence-diagrams](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/)

For now I can do something like into input.sequence

```
    A->B: Normal line
    B-->C: Dashed line
    C->>D: Open arrow
    D-->>A: Dashed open arrow
```

My question is what package you recommend to insert diagrams directly into markdown file example process.md :

```
# Conditions
Below the diagram explaining the process

    A->B: Normal line
    B-->C: Dashed line
    C->>D: Open arrow
    D-->>A: Dashed open arrow
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is off-topic as primarily opinion-based and also because it asks us to find or recommend an off-site resource. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hb.Sara,

Service like [typora](https://support.typora.io/Draw-Diagrams-With-Markdown/) should be helpful.

Otherwise, if you're looking to add sequence diagram to a markdown file as an extension and then push it to GitHub, for example, that may not work.

To get an image (a sequence diagram or otherwise) into a markdown file, you would need to use this syntax.

```
![An image of a dog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id207.png)
```

Even JS Sequence Diagrams themselves use this syntax in their [readme file](https://github.com/bramp/js-sequence-diagrams/blob/master/README.md). You could either store the image in the same repository or host the image externally (example: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id207.png)).

Hope this helps.